# How to remove default <p> tag from wp post content?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am facing a big problem to developing a wordpress theme. I want to show post content in  `<h2></h2>` 
But by default it is showing in `<p></p>`.Post content also have `<br>` . I want to keep this `<br>`and want to remove `<p></p>`. I have used this `remove_filter ('the_content',  'wpautop');` But it also remove `<br>`.

Please tell me how can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your functions.php file...

```
function my_wp_content_function($content) {

return strip_tags($content,"<br><h2>"); //add any tags here you want to preserve

}

add_filter('the_content', my_wp_content_function);
```

We're just using PHP's built-in strip_tags() function in concert with WordPress's add_filter() to custom format the_content() by telling it to remove all html tags while preserving the ones you do want (br and h2). wpautop is useful but not in the situation you're needing.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `<?php echo get_the_content(); ?>`, `<?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>`

Comment: `<?php echo get_the_content(); ?>` remove <br> from content